# в flexbox контейнере образуется не ясный отступ

Tags: flexbox

В коде [codepen](https://codepen.io/voyxxx/pen/eLmaoV) под изображением образуется отступ 4px. Можно решить добавив картинке `display: block;` или родителю картинки `margin: -4px;`

```css
.reason-one {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 256px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.reason-one div:first-child {
  background-color: #81b3d2;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 400px;
  flex-basis: 400px;
}

.reason-one h2 {
  margin: 54px 100px 0;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.reason-one span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.reason-one p {
  margin: 21px 45px 0;
}

.reason-one div:last-child img {
  /*   display: block; */
}
```

```html
<section class="reason-one">
  <div>
    <h2>настоящий городок</h2>
    <span>— №1 —</span>
    <p>седона — не аттракцион для туристов, там течёт своя жизнь</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/lGg3u.jpg" style="height: 256px">
  </div>
</section>
```

Помогите понять откуда берётся отступ и как его ловить, т.к. в web инспекторе не понятно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что картинка - это текст, она выравнивается по базовой линии текста, а между ней и низом строки есть зазор. Чтобы этого избежать, надо изменить `vertical-align` или `display`.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src=//www.gravatar.com/avatar/c6af686c7b79395bbb7fb1d10adaeded?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG>
</div>
<div>
  <img style=vertical-align:middle src=//www.gravatar.com/avatar/c6af686c7b79395bbb7fb1d10adaeded?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG>
</div>
<div>
  <img style=display:block src=//www.gravatar.com/avatar/c6af686c7b79395bbb7fb1d10adaeded?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG>
</div>
```